# run shortcode in excerpt of single custom post type

Tags: filters, shortcode, excerpt

Hi because of the way my theme is set up, I need to run a shortcode inside the excerpt of a custom post type (services). This is the code I have so far...

```
function do_my_shortcode_in_excerpt($excerpt) {
    if ( 'services' == get_post_type() ) {
        return do_shortcode(wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 55));
    }
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'do_my_shortcode_in_excerpt');
```

This works fine (I'll need to increase the 55) but it stops the excerpts appearing everywhere else. I only want this filter to run on excerpts associated with services - leaving other excerpts unaffected. Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to `return` the excerpt for the other post types.

Try for example:

```
function do_my_shortcode_in_excerpt( $excerpt ) 
{
    if ( 'services' == get_post_type() )
        $excerpt = do_shortcode( wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 55 ) );

    return $excerpt;    
}

add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'do_my_shortcode_in_excerpt' );
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I'd been playing around with `else` and got absolutely nowhere - I'd actually been putting too much code in. Thank you. If you see this birgire could I ask a related question - now that the shortcode is appearing I realize I may need to do some formatting, so allow spans, paragraphs etc. Can this be extended to allow html to be included within the services post type excerpt?

Comment: Apologies, I should explain - html code within the shortcode renders fine in excerpts but some excerpts do not contain shortcodes. They would benefit from some formatting / other html elements to generate a consistent look to those excerpts containing shortcodes. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi @PaulBrown. If you have a text containing HTML tags and cut out the first 55 words, then the problem is that you can get unclosed HTML tags. This could ruin the layout of the whole page. Maybe you can wrap the excerpts with some HTML tags and/or use some CSS to style it?

Comment: Hi @birgire thank you I understand. Perhaps easiest to show - this relates to a section on my front page http://skipology.com - you'll see 4 blocks part way down - the last block to the right of the section called 'new articles' is the one populated by the shortcode. The other 3 are excerpts populated from the entire content of the custom post type - therefore for this purpose there is no truncation (they are intended to be short). They contain paragraphs but just as shortcodes were stripped so are paragraph tags. If I created a shortcode for the content I could get the html in.

Comment: I wonder why you need to truncate it if it's intended to be short. You could maybe use some CSS to hide it if it get's to big, something like `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: Oh @birgire you've just completely changed how I thought about this. I need to track down the appropriate template and just change whatever is calling `the_excerpt` and call `the_content` instead I guess. I'll have a little play. thank you!